# Does docker-compose support placement constraints in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

in docs for compose-file
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

i have found reference to `constraints` as way to specify node in swarm

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
      - node.role == manager
      - engine.labels.operatingsystem == ubuntu 14.04
```

but it don't affect launch with `docker-compose up`

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==ryabchenko-system
```

here is my swarm

```
:~$ sudo docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME               STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
9q4y21c0u15rqp0x10164xzm9     ryabchenko-system      Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
se717p88485s22s715rdir9x2 *   speechanalytics-test   Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.3
```

on `speechanalytics-test` I run

```
:~$ sudo docker-compose -p ra -f docker-compose.yml up
```

and as result container is up on `speechanalytics-test`, but i want it to be on `ryabchenko-system`

Comment: I found that "placement constraints" work when i run 
 `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml ra`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placement constraints are only supported on swarm mode. The `docker-compose` command only works on single hosts so isn't supported there. You have to migrate your compose files for swarm usage and use `docker stack deploy` if you want to use the feature.